# Diagonalize a complex matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

We have a matrix $A =
\left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    0 & 1  \\
    -1 & 0  \\
  \end{array}
\right)$

I have found the eigenvalues to be simple and equal to 
$$\lambda_1 = i$$
$$\lambda_2 = -i$$

Computing the eigenvectors we have:$\left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    -i & 1  \\
    -1 & -i  \\
  \end{array}
\right)s_1 = 0$ and :$\left(
  \begin{array}{ccc}
    i & 1  \\
    -1 & i  \\
  \end{array}
\right)s_2 = 0$

What are the eigenvectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eigenvectors are solutions to the equation

$A v= \lambda v$.

Since you know both $A$ and $\lambda$, you can solve for $v$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_0\\v_1
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}
i v_0\\i v_1
\end{bmatrix}$$

In other words, you need to solve the linear equations:
$v_1=iv_0$ and $-v_0=iv_1$

The other eigenvector is just as easy.

Comment: I would say you need to solve either equation, not both.

Comment: Sure, in this case the linear equations are redundant, but in general you need to solve the complete system

Comment: It is a good practice to work with the complete system, but it is also important to know that it will *always* be redundant, since any combination of eigenvectors is also an eigenvector. In other words, the eigenvectors of an eigenvalue form a linear space.

Comment: I'm not sure if we're talking about the same thing here. I simply meant that the linear equations to solve for a particular eigenvector will not always be redundant like they are in the above example

Answer (score 0):

Hint matrix A is rotation matrix where $\theta=90$ you can write $i=cis(90)$ now do simple caculation which is usually done that is $(A-(cis(90)I_2)x=0$ you will get the eigenvectors.